# psycopg2 - UndefinedColumn: column "datetime" of relation "<table_name>" does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm getting this error message

```
UndefinedColumn: column "datetime" of relation "daily_price" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO public.daily_price (DateTime) VALUES ('200...
                                              ^
```

Code

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO public.daily_price (DateTime) VALUES ('"+str(day)+"')");
```

How to deal with the reserved word column without altering it on the database?

Comment: It's not complaining about a reserved word,.  It's complaining that the column doesn't exist.  What does the CREATE TABLE for `daily_crack_price` look like?

Comment: It exists 100% in the database.

Comment: I don't believe you.  Please show us the schema.

Comment: If the table name is actually DateTime and not datetime, you'll need to surround it with double quotes. `INSERT INTO public.daily_price ("DateTime") VALUES...`

Comment: Do not argue with the compiler, you will loose every time.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Roberts points out, you have a different problem.

Here is sample SQL that uses DateTime as a column name and executes successfully:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (DateTime timestamp);
INSERT INTO foo (DateTime) VALUES (now());
```

For completeness, here is what happens when you are truly using a reserved keyword that postgres objects to in context:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (select timestamp);
INSERT INTO foo (select) VALUES (now());

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (select timestamp);
                                    ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "VALUES"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO foo (select) VALUES (now());
```

To fix this case, you would use double-quotes:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo ("select" timestamp);
INSERT INTO foo ("select") VALUES (now());
```

This would work correctly - but this is not your problem.  Something you are not seeing is wrong with the schema.

Comment: like this???

cur.execute("INSERT INTO public.daily_price ("DateTime") VALUES ('"+str(day)+"')");

i dont think its working, issue with double quotes